# VBA Selenium Basic SendKeys to save pdf link

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

Im trying to build a code on vba selenium to save a pdf link from a website on edge browser, but i cannot send the "control+s" and "enter" keys to open the "save as" windows tab and save it. Can somebody help?

This is the code that im trying to use:

```
obj.SendKeys ("^s")
obj.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
```

I already tried a lot of options none of them worked.

```
obj.SendKeys ("^s")
obj.SendKeys ("^(s)")
obj.SendKeys ("{^}{s}")
obj.SendKeys ("ENTER")
obj.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: What is `obj` in the code?

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand much about vba and selenium but im trying to learn.
I suppose that is the variable...

`Dim obj As New WebDriver`

Comment: The WebDriver object doesn't have a `sendKeys()` method it seems. You need to find the element you want and use the method on that?https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebElement.html Special keys are declared as `Key.ENTER` etc: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Key.html#NULL. `sendKeys` takes the special keys in sequence and have to be released eg: element.sendKeys("text was",
                   Key.CONTROL, "a", Key.NULL,
                   "now text is");